# R: regex to grep all first occurrence of percentage ([0-9]*%)

Tags: regex, r, string

```
string <- c("50% something", "something100% more", "Both6% and also60%")
```

I cannot figure how to get the first occurrence of the number before '%'. Note that all sorts of characters can occur in `string`. My result from `string` above would be:

```
[1]  50 100   6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `str_extract` from `stringr` to extract the first set of numbers before `%`.  Here, I used lookaround `(?=%)` to match digits followed by `%`

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(str_extract(string, '\\d+(?=%)'))
#[1]  50 100   6
```

For the second case

```
 string1 <- c(string, "50people but 20%")
 as.numeric(str_extract(string1, '\\d+(?=%)'))
 #[1]  50 100   6  20
```

Comment: Of cause, so simple!  Forgot about `stringr` .

Comment: And in the case of  "50people but 20%" this would go as  str_extract(string, '\\d+%').

Comment: @user3375672  It gives 20 based on the code I used.  I guess you want to extract only numbers before `%`

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Perfect with the lookaround.

Answer (score 3):

Use sub,

```
> string <- c("50% something", "something100% more", "Both6% and also60%")
> sub("^.*?(\\d+)%.*", "\\1", string)
[1] "50"  "100" "6"  
> as.numeric(sub("^.*?(\\d+)%.*", "\\1", string))
[1]  50 100   6
```